# Transient fields in Spring session-scoped controller

Tags: spring, session, logging, spring-3

I have a Spring controller bean set to a session scope, it looks somewhat like this:

```
@Controller
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class SessionTestController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7735095657091576437L;

    private transient Log log;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initialise() {
        log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String doGet() throws InterruptedException {
        log.warn("This line will fail after deserialisation..."); // Causes NPE
    }

}
```

It seems Spring does not call `@PostConstruct` after de-serialisation, this causes my "log" field to become null and throw a NullPointerException in my `doGet()` method.

How do you usually deal with non-serialisable fields like the logger in session-scoped beans? Do I need to implement some session aware interface to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a typical way is to use `readObject()` to initialize `transient` fields, no matter whether it's a Spring bean or not:

```
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream stream)
     throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    stream.defaultReadObject();
    initializeTransientFields();
}
```

Comment: I think I had gone down a bad path with this @PostConstruct attempt. I would expect this is the correct solution.

Comment: In the case of my example, I made my logger static and fixed the class name argument `LogFactory.getLog(SessionTestController.class);`, but some of my other fields now use `readObject`. Thanks!